# How do you solve script library conflicts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, web

I took over a web project and there are many libraries used. JQuery, javascript, bootstrap, d3 to name a few.

I'm running into some IE issues as the site is supposed to be optimized for Chrome and IE.  One notable and big issue for the client is that the "back to the top" button is not working in IE and I can't figure out why.  I've used several different techniques and they all work standalone, but not in my environment.  My question is how can I properly solve this issue.  I know it's not a browser issue because the "back to the top" works fine in IE standalone.
Is there an easy solution to this?  where do I start?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />


<title>Station 10</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  

<!-- Custom Theme CSS -->



<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/selectize.css" type="text/css" media="all" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/table.css" type="text/css" media="all" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css" />       
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/application_style_new_format.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/hover-min.css">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/application_old.js"></script>


<style>
#mainpic {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
margin-left:-150px;
margin-top:-150px
}
#box1 {
position:absolute;
left:60%;
top:30%;
margin-left:-150px;
margin-top:-150px
}
</style>
<script> 


</script>

</head>

<body style= "display:inline-block; background: none; width:100vw;" >  
<div id="scroll_wrapper" class="col-md-8">

     <div id="sidenavContainer" class="sidenavContainer" style= "display:inline-block; ">

         <!-- Sidebar Links -->
         <nav id="sidebar">     
                <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe" style="margin-top:0px;">
                    <li ><a href="index.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -22px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/home.png" alt="home" border="0"></a></li> 
                    <li  style="left: -22px;z-index:3;margin-top:7px;"><a  href="index.html">HOME </a></li>
               </ul> 

               <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:4px;">
                    <li class="myimg1"><a href="station1.html"><img   id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/1_selected.png" alt="station1" border="0"></a></li> 

                     <li style="left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:16px;"> <a  href="station1.html">Overview</a></li>
                </ul>

                 <ul id="activeStation" class="list-unstyled components tileMe main-menu list-dropdown" style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:3px;">
                     <li><a href="station2.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/2.png" alt="station1"  border="0"></a></li> 

                    <li  style="left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:16px;"> <a  href="station2.html">Data Input</a></li>

                     <li  style="margin-left: 105px;z-index:30;margin-top:24px;"><img  src="assets/img/subpage_arrow.png" alt="subpage"  border="0"></li> 

                   <ul class="collapse list-unstyled tileMe submenu" id="homeSubmenu" style="margin-left: 10.2px; margin-top:-2px;margin-bottom:-2px;display:none">
                            <li class="tileMe" ><a style="font-size: 14px !important; font-family:'Arial'; margin-left: -0.5px;z-index:3;margin-top:-25px;margin-bottom:-5px;" href="station2.html#coverage">                          
                                <img  src="assets/img/subpages.png" alt="subpage"  border="0" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Coverage</a></li>
                            <li class="tileMe" ><a style="font-size: 14px !important; font-family:'Arial';margin-left: -0.5px;z-index:3;margin-top:-6px;margin-bottom:-1px;" href="station2.html#wrapper7">
                                <img  src="assets/img/subpages.png" alt="subpage"  border="0" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Macro Data</a></li>
                            <li class="tileMe" ><a style="font-size: 14px !important; font-family:'Arial'; margin-left: -0.5px;z-index:3;margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:-6px;" href="station2.html#wrapper11">
                                <img  src="assets/img/subpages.png" alt="subpage"  border="0" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Debt Data</a></li>
                        </ul> 

                </ul>


                <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe" style="margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:3px;">
                     <li><a href="station3.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/3.png" alt="station1"  border="0"></a></li> 

                    <li style="left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:16px;">  <a  href="station3.html">Realism</a></li>


                </ul>


                <ul id="activeStation" class="list-unstyled components tileMe main-menu list-dropdown" style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:3px;">
                     <li><a href="station4.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/4.png" alt="station1"  border="0"></a></li> 

                    <li  style="left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:16px;">  <a  href="station4.html">Debt-Carrying Capacity</a></li>

                     <li  style="margin-left: 23px;z-index:30;margin-top:24px;"><img  src="assets/img/subpage_arrow.png" alt="subpage"  border="0"></li> 

                      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled tileMe submenu" id="homeSubmenu" style="margin-left: 10.2px; margin-top:-2px;margin-bottom:-2px;display:none">
                            <li class="tileMe" ><a style="font-size: 14px !important; font-family:'Arial'; margin-left: -0.5px;z-index:3;margin-top:-25px;margin-bottom:-15px;" href="station4.html#wrapper4">                          
                                <img  src="assets/img/subpages.png" alt="subpage"  border="0" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Composite Indicator</a></li>
                            <li class="tileMe" ><a style="font-size: 14px !important; font-family:'Arial';margin-left: -0.5px;z-index:3;margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:-15px;" href="station4.html#wrapper8">
                                <img  src="assets/img/subpages.png" alt="subpage"  border="0" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Thresholds and Benchmarks</a></li>

                        </ul> 


                </ul>


               <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe" style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:4px;">
                    <li><a href="station5.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/5.png" alt="station1" border="0"></a></li> 

                    <li  style="left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:16px;"> <a  href="station5.html">Stress Tests</a></li>


                </ul>


                <ul id="activeStation" class="list-unstyled components tileMe main-menu list-dropdown" style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:3px;">
                      <li><a href="station6.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/6.png" alt="station1"  border="0"></a></li> 

                    <li  style="left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:16px;font-weight: bold;">  <a  href="station6.html">Outputs</a></li>
                     <li  style="margin-left: 116px;z-index:30;margin-top:20px;"><img  src="assets/img/subpage_arrow.png" alt="subpage"  border="0"></li> 


                     <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe main-menu list-dropdown" id="homeSubmenu" style="margin-left: 10.2px; margin-top:-2px;margin-bottom:-2px;display:none">
                            <li class="tileMe" ><a style="font-size: 14px !important; font-family:'Arial'; margin-left: -0.5px;z-index:3;margin-top:-19px;margin-bottom:-5px;" href="station6.html#wrapper2">                       
                                <img  src="assets/img/subpages.png" alt="subpage"  border="0" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;DSA Baseline Tables</a></li>
                            <li class="tileMe" ><a style="font-size: 14px !important; font-family:'Arial';margin-left: -0.5px;z-index:3;margin-top:-12px;margin-bottom:-4px;" href="station6.html#wrapper8">
                                <img  src="assets/img/subpages.png" alt="subpage"  border="0" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Baseline & Stress Test Charts</a></li>
                            <li class="tileMe" ><a style="font-size: 14px !important; font-family:'Arial'; margin-left: -0.5px;z-index:3;margin-top:-12px;margin-bottom:-14px;" href="station6.html#wrapper11">
                                <img  src="assets/img/subpages.png" alt="subpage"  border="0" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sensitivity Analysis Tables</a></li>
                        </ul> 

                </ul>


               <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe" style="margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:3px;">
                    <li><a href="station7.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/7.png" alt="station1"  border="0"></a></li> 

                    <li  style="left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:16px;">  <a  href="station7.html">Market Financing</a></li>


                </ul>
               <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe" style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:4px;">
                     <li><a href="station8.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/8.png" alt="station1"  border="0"></a></li> 

                    <li  style="left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:16px;">  <a  href="station8.html">Judgement</a></li>


                </ul>


                <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe " style="margin-top:3px;">
                     <li><a href="station9.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/9.png" alt="station1"  border="0"></a></li> 

                    <li   style="margin-left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:16px;margin-bottom:1px;"> <a  href="station9.html">Final Risk Rating</a> </li>

                </ul>


                     <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe" style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:2px;">
                     <li><a href="station10.html"><img  id="removeRightNav" style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/10.png" alt="station1"  border="0"></a></li> 

                    <li  style="margin-left: 17px;z-index:30;margin-top:16px;margin-bottom:-2px;">  <a  href="station10.html">Granularity</a></li> 
                </ul>


                <ul class="list-unstyled components tileMe" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:1px;">
                     <li><a href="help.html"><img style="left: -17px;z-index:3;" src="assets/img/help.png" alt="help" border="0"></a></li>

                    <li  style="left: 17px;z-index:3;margin-top:8px;">  <a href="help.html">HOW CAN WE HELP</a></li>
                </ul>


         </nav>
<!-- End of Navigation -->
</div>



<div id="main" class="main" id="page-top" style= "display:inline-block; background: white;"> 


       <section id="wrapper" class="slide" >
          <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100vh;" >



               <div  id="imf-home">
                    <div class="star-background">
                        <div class="star-background-fade" style="height:10px;"></div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
   </section>

       <section class="slide1" id="wrapper1" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 
                    <div id="mainpic">
    <img src="assets/img/station2/S02_CvgofPubSect_V4.png"/>
 </div>
 <div id="box1">
 <img src="assets/img/button_dots-white.png" width="30px;" />
                    </div>

                </div>
   </section>                 

        <section class="slide2" id="wrapper2" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 50px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section> 

         <section class="slide3" id="wrapper3" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section>

                    <section class="slide4" id="wrapper4" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
        </section>                 

        <section class="slide5" id="wrapper5" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 50px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section> 

         <section class="slide6" id="wrapper6" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section>
                    <section class="slide7" id="wrapper7" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
        </section>                 

        <section class="slide8" id="wrapper8" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 50px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section> 

         <section class="slide9" id="wrapper9" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section>
                    <section class="slide10" id="wrapper10" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
        </section>

        <section class="slide11" id="wrapper11" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
        </section>                  

        <section class="slide12" id="wrapper12" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 50px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section> 

         <section class="slide13" id="wrapper13" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section>

         <section class="slide14" id="wrapper14" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section>                 

         <section class="slide15" id="wrapper15" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 50px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section> 

         <section class="slide16" id="wrapper16" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section>
         <section class="slide17" id="wrapper17" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section>                 

         <section class="slide18" id="wrapper18" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 50px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section> 

         <section class="slide19" id="wrapper19" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 90px;width: 800px; float:left;">
                <div class="newslide-content" style="display:block; float:left;"> 

                </div>
         </section>    


</div> <!-- end main middle section --> 

  <div class="sidenavright" style="display:inline-block;"> 
        <div id="stacked" css="stackedActive">

           <!-- <img  src="assets/img/banner_monk_train.jpg" alt="home" width="290" height="80" border="0">-->
        </div>

</div> 

 </div>  <!-- end of scroll -->  
 <div id="myBtn">
  <a class="hashscroll" href="#wrapper1"><img src="assets/img/scroll_up_hover.png" width="50px" height="50px" /></a>
 </div>       


</body>
</html>
```

See it here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shopmaster/3uc15a0s/10/embedded/result,css,html,js)

Comment: You start by following the advice in [mcve]

Comment: @quentin Thanks for the advice. Much appreciated. Hopefully my edits are a little more useful. The back to the top button that appears after some scroll does not even show up in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The code that's supposed to display and hide the button is the following:

```
//Scroll To Top Function
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 1040 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1040) {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

However, in IE, both `document.body.scrollTop` and `document.documentElement.scrollTop` always return 0 so the condition is never true.

You have to find the right condition that works on your version of IE

Comment: Thanks @YoukouleleY but standalone this worked in IE for the example but is not working with my site that's why I think it's more of a script issue and not a browser issue.  Here is the stand alone version that works in IE. [working example in IE](https://html-online.com/demo/scroll-to-top/)

Comment: By "my site" you mean your jsfiddle?

Comment: I stand corrected it has to be a browser issue because when I chose "display: block" in the css from "display: none" it shows up.

So something is not kicking off that change and as you suggest it has to do with IE not recognizing the condition.